# Concatenation specified sequence

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, concatenation

I have task, implement next - Copies six characters from the source (string) to destination (string). First string looks like - "example_da", second - "this_is_*******_", so task consiste from copy "source" (only "example") and insert it to interval *******. But when try to use source.ToCopy i get - **Index and count must refer to a location within the string** (But if length is 15, why i can't do it)

Nested code :

```
 public static string CopySixChars(string source, string destination)
    {

        char[] destinationArray = destination.ToCharArray();

        source.CopyTo(4, destinationArray, 0, source.Length);

        return new string(destinationArray);
    }
```

Comment: Forget to add the main problem )

Comment: It might be frustrating you at this point and it's worth you doing some simple String Tutorials to learn. I can give you the answer `dest = source.Substring(0,6);` but you'll need to know how to do all these types of things (without having to ask on Stackovereflow) so I suggest more study with hands on exercises...

Comment: @JeremyThompson , Yes, most likely it was necessary to read the documentation, although my previous code for the concatenation methods has Substring  (I just went to bed 2 hours ago). I recently used it, sorry for the stupid question and thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can refer to this.

Syntax:

```
public void CopyTo (
int source_index, //index to the string from where you want to copy the string
char[] destination, //target character array in which you want to copy the part of the string
int destination_index, //index in the targeted character array
int count//total number of characters to be copied in character array
);
```

Main:

```
string a = "example_da";
string b = "this_is_*******_";
Console.WriteLine( CopySixChars(a, b));
```

Nested code :

```
public static string CopySixChars(string source, string destination) {
            char[] destinationArray = destination.ToCharArray();
            source.CopyTo(0,destinationArray,8,6);
            return new string(destinationArray);
        }
```

Print:

[image]

Comment: Does it help you？Please give me a reply to help you better.